# Firebase y sincronización con Base de datos SQL server

Tags: android, sql-server, firebase

Quisiera usar `FireBase` en una aplicación como base de datos.
La idea sería que una app en Android estuviera sincronizada con `firebase` pero también necesito que `Firebase` reciba y envié datos a una base de datos que tengo en un equipo con `SQL server` . Es decir la arquitectura seria del tipo:

Android <====> firebase <====> SQL server

La integración entre `Android` y `Firebase` la tengo clara, pero tengo muchas dudas de como sincronizar los datos desde `Firebase` hasta  `SQL server` y viceversa, es decir de mi base de datos SQL hasta `Firebase` .
¿Alguna idea y/o tecnologías a usar?

Comment: No estoy seguro de como hacer la comunicación de SQL Server a firebase, pero sí al revés (Necesitas utilizar las Cloud Functions de Firebase e implementar la comunicación con SQL Server mediante NodeJS)

Comment: Gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar cloud functions para conectarte a una [API REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#integrate_with_third-party_services_and_apis), puedes programar un [trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) en el evento que necesites (update, insert, delete) y lanzar la función para que se actualice la base de datos SQL.
El esquema básico sería así 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la comunicación de SQL a firebase puedes utilizar la API de javascript para crear servicios o web workers que sincronicen ambas BD, pero quedaría de tu lado distinguir que es lo que se debe actualizar.

Quizás te convendría ver [Realm](https://realm.io/), tienen esa funcionalidad out of the box pero tiene un costo alto (creo que  [1500 dolares mensuales](https://realm.io/pricing/))

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Perdona a que funcionalidad te refieres que tiene Realm? conectar el dispositivo móvil con una base  de datos y luego mandar esos datos a nuestro servidor?

Comment: si @JoCuTo es algo que mencionan en Real como "API bridge" puedes ver mas detalles en https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!